# Aerospace bolts and washer combination

Tags: aerospace-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, fasteners

In my aerospace company we have repetitive discussions regarding the stacking of low tolerance fasteners with non-countersunk washers. For example a fastner NAS6703-X (size 10) has a max. base radius of .02". A non-countersunk washer NAS1149 size 10 would clash with the base radius if modelled.

Having done a fit check, there is no clash but to avoid issues we have used bigger sized washers on some occasions. I find it odd to use different sized bolt/washer combinations.

Are you aware of any guidance material regarding this, respectively has anyone else met this topic?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't you have to follow the material build specs /. documentation to continue to meet certification?

Comment: We are the type design holder so the documentation/design is from us. I was hoping there is some guideline regarding standard parts to streamline the design. I was just wondering why two fastener parts can have clashes when the tolerances acc. to spec are being used.

Comment: In your design guidelines, how much deformation is allowed for the washer? There is some assumption in the usage of washers that your washer will deform anyway, at least in non-aerospace applications.

Comment: We have no such guideline internally. The concern from stress dept. is that a washer clashing with the head radius will weaken the bolt and shall therefore be avoided.

Comment: I would go back to the NAS documents for guidance.  Certainly you don't need software to determine if a washer fits the head without interference.  I would start with what the math says about the OD right below the head.  If there is interference from the basic math I would question manufacturers.  Do they know this and as a result build to the "right side" of tolerances?  My last thought is wondering if the standard just assumes the washer will be used on the a nut only and not the bolt head.